# COUNTIFS with dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, countif

I'm trying to get the **number of support tickets for each month**. In my first tab "Tickets" I have:

[image]

The date values have the following characteristics:

[image]

In my second tab I have:

[image]

I want to know how much tickets for each month. I've tried this:

```
= COUNTIFS(Tickets!B2:B196;">=1/06/17";Tickets!B2:B196;"<=31/06/17")
```

But that results in 0, which is not correct. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of accomplishing this, however the easiest would be as follows:

```
=COUNTIFS(Tickets!B2:B196;">=DATEVALUE(1/06/17)";Tickets!B2:B196;"<=DATEVALUE(31/06/17)")
```

This will convert the dates to a date serial, which will match the data format within each cell.

Alternately, you could use either a helper column with:

```
=MONTH([cell])
```

You would then do the COUNTIF on the helper column.

As a third option, you could use an array formula similar to the following:

```
=IF(MONTH([range])=[number 1-12],COUNT([range]))
```

*Press ctrl+shift+enter to activate*

The important thing to remember is that dates are stored as a serial number since 01/01/1900 including 02/29/1900, and MONTH returns an integer.